# How to copy a file from one user's home to another user's home

Tags: linux, file-transfer, file-permissions

So I have userA, and userB, I have password for userA to login, and somebody already setup for me that when I am login as userA, I can do `sudo su - userB` to switch to userB.

the setup works as (and I don't know how this is setup)

1. userA does not have root access, and `sudo su - userB` does not ask for password.
2. userB does not have password, so the only way I can login as userB is to use command in 1.
3. userA and userB does not have access to files in each other's home

Now how can I copy file from userB's home to userA's home?

UPDATE: tried the command suggested below and the system ask for sudo password for all the command suggested. except `sudo su - userB`

```
userA@hostname:~$ sudo su -c any_command userB
[sudo] password for userA:
userA@hostname:~$ sudo su - userB
userB@hostname:~$
```

Comment: Are you sure user A does not have root access? (By default, unless special steps were taken to restrict it, being able to use `sudo` is _literally_ root access.)

Comment: Does the system allow variations such as `sudo -u userB -i`, or `sudo -u userB whoami`, or `sudo su -c "whoami" userB`?

Comment: @user1686 all the commands you suggested askes for sudo password....

Answer (score 0):

its a wierd workaround but...

As userA:

cp [file] /tmp/

Then as userB:

cp /tmp/[file] .

(or /home/userb/desktop instead of .)

Answer (score 0):

Simply using cat and pipes should be ok and allows you to do this with a simple command

For userA to userB, login as userA and :
cat /home/userA/file_to_copy | sudo su -c "cat >/home/userB/file_copied" userB

For userB to userA, login as userA and :
sudo su -c "cat /home/userB/file_to_copy" userB | cat > /home/userA/file_copied